# Associating the key in one dictionary to the values in another dictionary

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries. 1 of them shows people and activities they like.

```
my_dict= {'bob': ['skiing',
  'soccer',
  'ballet'],
 'Angela': ['skiing',
  'ballet',
  'hiking'] }
```

and so on...

The other dictionary shows the number of people in each activity, like so:

```
my_dict1= {'skiing': 5,
 'soccer': 8,
 'ballet': 33,
 'hiking': 2 }
```

and so on...

I would like the resulting dictionary to look like this:

```
my_dict= {'bob': 46,
 'Angela': 40 }
```

I need to assign the value of my_dict1 to the associated value in my_dict. Then I need to sum them. For example, `'bob': 46` is derived from `'bob': 5+8+33`

Comment: please attempt to solve this on your own and report issue you have

Comment: You didn't actually ask a *question* here. Did you get stuck implementing this somewhere?

Comment: Side note: your values in `my_dict1` and `my_dict` are lists with a single element. Why do you need these to be lists? Can they be simplified to just be mappings from *activity* to *number* and *name* to *value*.

Comment: you're right  @MartijnPieters, I have changed my_dict1 so the values aren't lists anymore. I'm not sure what you mean by " Can they be simplified to just be mappings from activity to number and name to value" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_dict= {'bob': ['skiing',
  'soccer',
  'ballet'],
 'Angela': ['skiing',
  'ballet',
  'hiking'] }



my_dict1= {'skiing': 5,
 'soccer': 8,
 'ballet': 33,
 'hiking': 2 }


new_dic ={}

for i in my_dict:
    new_dic[i]=sum([my_dict1[i] for i in my_dict[i]])

print(new_dic)
```

Comment: Thank you. When I try this, i'm getting the error: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Ashley when you run this code you are getting error ? or when running this on whole orinal dic you are getting error ?

Comment: It is when i run it on the original dictionary. the values of my_dict1  are all ints, I wonder if that is the problem?

Comment: user in that case `new_dic[str(i)]`

Comment: unforunately i'm getting the same error when i try: ```new_dic[str(i)]=[sum([my_dict1[i][0] for i in my_dict[i]])]``` and when i try  ```new_dic[str(i)]=[sum([my_dict1[i][0] for i in my_dict[str(i)]])] ```

Comment: @Ashley sorry my wrongness, you need to check that `my_dict1[i]` are all list or int value only . error is here. if it is int then code need to modify else of list it is running fine

Comment: the values of of my_dict1 are all ints. I cant access ```my_dict1``` using ```my_dict1[1]```. How do I access my_dict1 when my values are ints?

Comment: check updated solution